# How to save PDF form(user fills and submit) data into Database using java

Tags: java, pdf

Here is my scenario,

"user opens the PDF in web browser and fills required data and clicks the submit button",

How do i save the above PDF data into database using java technology,

i tried with iText lib and servlets concepts, unable to finish the task,

thanks all, looking for help

Comment: May be adobe live cycle help you. http://forums.adobe.com/thread/333081.

Answer (score 2):

You might to have a look at the [Apache PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/) library.

Comment: thanks u very much for ur support, i will try with above links

Answer (score 0):

You can create a PDF that submits to a URL. At the URL, you can run a server-side script (PHP or ASP.NET) that processes the submitted form contents. The server-side script can save the form data to your database.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to extract form data from PDF documents using [PDFTextStream](http://snowtide.com/?lang=java).  There is some sample code right on that first landing page to get you started; you can also dig into [the details of form data extraction with PDFTextStream](http://www.snowtide.com/help/extracting-updating-pdf-form-data) when you're ready.

(Disclosure: I am employed by Snowtide, the makers of PDFTextStream.  I hope this pointer is helpful in any case.)

Answer (score 0):

PDF Form submit button have special function, that support submit via http, and need write java code to parse the submitted form and save the data to database. you can have a look this example,http://rubypdf.appspot.com/demo.pdf